# Mysql SELECT specific json value from string

Tags: mysql, json

Hello, I am trying to select a value from json string in the Mysql query.
My table looks like this.
I am trying to select title and value of tags id:2 at the same time WHEN id = x

```
id | title    | tags 
------------------------------------------------------
1  | title 1  | [{"id":"1","value":"value of id 1"},{"id":"2","value":"value of id 2"}]
2  | title 2  | [{"id":"1","value":"value of id 1"},{"id":"2","value":"value of id 2"}]
3  | title 3  | [{"id":"1","value":"value of id 1"},{"id":"2","value":"value of id 2"}]
```

So far, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT title, tags FROM table WHERE id=2;
```

But as you can see, this return the entire tags string. 
Will it be possible to select just the value of tags with "**id":"2"**

Comment: This will give you a headache. I recommend either laod the complete table and deserialize it in your app or store the values of your json string seperately.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, it can create lots of headaches but if you are still hellbent on having a solution for this then you can consider using `INSTR` or `LOCATE` to get the index of the string "id":"X" (where X is the value that you are looking for, followed by a `SUBSTRING` to extract the string from the position you got earlier till the position where `}` is encountered.